# DB Designer 4, Connection to database failed, Unable to load oci.dll

Tags: database

I receive this error "Connection to database failed. Unable to Load OCI.dll ":  when trying to create a new Oracle Connection. I want to import this connection in SQL developer.

How can I make it load the OCI.dll file?

Please Help!